# Geometrical construction of the product on $\mathbb R$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, geometric-construction

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Representing the multiplication of two numbers on the real line](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/139340/representing-the-multiplication-of-two-numbers-on-the-real-line)

Consider the real line in the plane. Suppose you are given the location of the point associated to $0$ and two oter points $a$ and $b$ on the line, it's strightforward to provide a geometric construction(*) that allows you to identify the point associated to $a+b$. My question is: suppose we are given the locations of $0$ and $1$, given two points $a$ and $b$ can we provide a geometric construction which allows to identify the point $a \cdot b$?

(*) [Compass and straightedge construction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compass_and_straightedge_constructions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using similar triangles. Suppose we have a triangle with sides $1$, $a$, and $c$ (some length whose exact size does not matter). If we now get a similar triangle with sides $b$ times bigger, we now have a triangle whose sides are of length $b$, $a \cdot b$, and $b \cdot c$.

1. Construct a triangle $ABC$ where $|AB|=1$ and $|AC|=a$. It does not matter what the length of $BC$ is.
2. Extend the side $AB$ to get a line and find the point $D$ on this line (on the same side of $A$ as $B$) such that $|AD|=b$.
3. Draw a line $L$ through $D$ parallel to $BC$.
4. Extend the side $AC$ until it intersects the line $L$ at the point $E$. The line segment $AE$ has length $a \cdot b$. (This follows from the properties of [similar triangles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Similarity_%28geometry%29)).

For further details see the lecture notes at this [website](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/Courses/math119/).

Comment: Thak you, the notes are very nice.