# Geometric model of real numbers

Tags: real-numbers, geometric-construction

I'm looking for a way to multiply real numbers using only geometric techniques.
Suppose we already know how to halve a real number and multiply a real number with a natural in a geometric way.

For the multiplication of two real I thought to do this:

$ a=[a]+\left \{ a \right \} $

$ b=[b]+\left \{ b \right \} $

in square brackets indicate the integer part (segment equal or multiple of the whole unit) and the other indicates the fractional part (shorter segment of the unit).
Then:

$ ab=[a][b]+[a]\left \{ b \right \}+\left \{ a \right \}[b]+\left \{ a \right \}\left \{ b \right \} $

The first 3 addenda can be "calculated" geometrically, the last in general no.

$ \left \{ a \right \} $ and $ \left \{ b \right \} $ are both shorter segments of the unit.

Then I begin to double both $ n_1 $ times until both have passed the unit.
I'll get $ a'=2^{n_1}\left \{ a \right \} $ and $ b'= 2^{n_1}\left \{ b \right \} $

At this point I can continue building the product-segment in this way (since I know how to halve a number):

$ \left \{ a \right \}\left \{ b \right \}=\frac{a'b'}{2^{2n_1}}=\frac{[a'][b']}{2^{2n_1}}+\frac{[a']\left \{ b' \right \}}{2^{2n_1}}+\frac{\left \{ a' \right \}[b']}{2^{2n_1}}+\frac{\left \{ a' \right \}\left \{ b' \right \}}{2^{2n_1}} $

again I do not know how to "calculate" the last numerator but I can do the same thing by getting:

$ \left \{ a' \right \}\left \{ b' \right \}=\frac{a''b''}{2^{2n_2}}=\frac{[a''][b'']}{2^{2n_2}}+\frac{[a'']\left \{ b'' \right \}}{2^{2n_2}}+\frac{\left \{ a'' \right \}[b'']}{2^{2n_2}}+\frac{\left \{ a'' \right \}\left \{ b'' \right \}}{2^{2n_2}} $

with $ a''=2^{n_2}\left \{ a' \right \} $ and $ b''= 2^{n_2}\left \{ b' \right \} $ and again only the last numerator will have to be expanded and so on... (until one of the two fractional parts become null or until infinite if necessary and if I want infinite precision)

Do you have better methods?

Thanks and sorry if my English is not very good.

Comment: Can you do right angle constructions?

Comment: Con you make an example of what you want to do?

Comment: See this question:   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/139340/representing-the-multiplication-of-two-numbers-on-the-real-line

Comment: @ChristianBlatter Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is a better way, I think. First, you have to be given a segment of unit length, otherwise multiplication doesn't make sense. Now if you have $a$ and $b$, you can construct $h$ so that $h^2=a\cdot b$, using the [geometric mean theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_mean_theorem). After that, you use the same $h=CD$ and your unit segment $1$ to find the $x$ satisfying $h^2=x\cdot1$: the unit segment is then $DB$, you find the circle with midpoint $M$ on the line through $B$ and $D$ ($M$ is where the perpendicular bisector of $BC$ hits the line through $D$ and $B$), the circle will have a second intersection point $A$ with the line through $BD$, so $x=a\cdot b/1$ will be $AD$.
[image: geometric mean theorem]

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand this last part "just taking the unit segment as segment b, finding M, the resulting segment a will be our x."
So I have to draw another real line with a different scale (unit segment on the new real line is the b segment on the old real line), and then...?
Why is point M important for me?

Comment: @Biagio Ianero I've added a few details, is it more understandable, now?

Comment: Yes, thank you.
I've also replied for adding the construction of the inverse, and so now one can geometrically build the number a/b.

Answer (score 0):

So now I can also build in a similar way the inverse, and so the number $a/b$, as shown in the next image.

[1/a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IA3Yg.png)

Right?