# If we can construct lines of distance $1$ and $x$, then how do we construct a line of distance $x^2$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometry, field-theory, galois-theory

The author is trying to prove it is impossible to square a circle of radius $1$ under the assumption that $\pi$ is transcendental. Even with this assumption, the author explains that if the circle can be squared, then we could draw a line with distance $\pi^{1/2}$. Everything good at the moment. Then he claims that, if such construction is possible, we could also draw a line of distance $\pi$, and that the proof would, under the stated assumption, be complete.

> The thing I don't get is how, from a line with distance $\pi^{1/2}$, we could create a line with distance $\pi$.

Comment: Not following.  Were $\pi$ constructible (a special case of algebraic) then it would be possible to square your circle, not impossible.  As to your construction question, if $x,y$ are constructible then so is $xy$.  See, e.g., [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/139340/representing-the-multiplication-of-two-numbers-on-the-real-line)

Comment: Once a segment has been chosen that defines the distance $1$ in the plane, we have short constructions for addition, subtraction, multiplication and division of segment lengths; we also have squaring and square root.

Comment: @lulu. I made a big typo. $/pi$ is assumed to be transcendental*.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

(This space intentionally left blank.)

Comment: Thank you. Though, how do you make the right angles?

Comment: @Leo: Right angles are easy ... https://www.wikihow.com/Construct-a-90-Degrees-Angle-Using-Compass-and-Ruler