# How can I draw a line with length "a^2"?

Tags: geometry

I have a line whose length is "a". Can anyone explain procedure of drawing following lines?

1-line whose length is "a^2"

2-line whose length is "sqrt(a)"

Comment: Do you also have a line of length 1?

Comment: I've marked this as a duplicate for the construction of the square of a length. See [my solution there](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2510005/409). (As @martycohen remarks in his answer below: It's all in Euclid.) For the square root, you can use the same construction, simply replacing $x^2$ with $x$, and $x$ with $\sqrt{x}$.

Answer (score 1):

As Rahul wrote,
you need to have a line of
length 1.

Once you have this,
you can use similar triangles
to solve
$\dfrac{1}{a}
=\dfrac{a}{x}
$
so that
$x = a^2$.

To find $\sqrt{a}$,
draw a circle
with diameter
$1+a$
and erect a perpendicular
to a diameter
a distance $1$
from the end.
Where this intersects the circle,
it makes a right triangle
with the diameter,
and the altitude $x$
satisfies
$\dfrac{1}{x}
=\dfrac{x}{a}
$
so that
$x^2 = a$
or
$x = \sqrt{a}$.

Nothing original here - 
it's all in Euclid.